# Moving a cursor with the keyboard in assembly

Tags: beginner, console, assembly

I am a beginner in assembly. But that didn't stop me from making a simple operating system completely made in assembly. It's very simple and doesn't do much. It's just a proof of concept. I would like to know what I can improve. Any feedback would be great.

```
bits 16
mov dl, 0 ; Cursor position column
mov dh, 0 ; Cursor position row

; Draw a really simple UI
; Draws a blue background
mov ah, 09h 
mov al, 32
mov bl, 10h
mov cx, 1000h
int 10h 

; Draws a gray bar
mov ah, 09h
mov al, 32
mov bl, 70h
mov cx, 160d
int 10h

main:
    ; Waits for a key press
    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h

    ; Compare the al register to see what key the user pressed

    ; If the user pressed the 's' key move the cursor down
    cmp al, 115
    je Down

    ; If the user pressed the 'w' key move the cursor up
    cmp al, 119
    je Up

    ; If the user pressed the 'a' key move the cursor left
    cmp al, 97
    je Left

    ; If the user pressed the 'd' key move the cursor right
    cmp al, 100
    je Right

    ; If the user pressed the Space Bar make the background of the   cursor magenta
    cmp al, 32
    je SpaceBar

    ; Jump back to main
    jmp main

    ; Our functions
    SpaceBar:
          mov ah, 09h
          mov bl, 50h
          mov cx, 1d
          int 10h
          jmp main  

    Right:
        add dl, 1
        call SetCursor
        jmp main
        ret

    Left:
      sub dl, 1
      call SetCursor
      jmp main
      ret

   Up:
     sub dh, 1
     call SetCursor
     jmp main
     ret

   Down:
      add dh, 1
      call SetCursor
      jmp main
      ret

   SetCursor:
       mov ah, 02h
       mov bh, 00
       int 10h
       ret

 times 510-($-$$) db 0
 dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: Which variant of Assembly are you using? x86 assembly?

Comment: @EBrown I'm really not sure actually. But I would say yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program uses many BIOS functions that require you to set the display page beforehand in the `BH` register. You specified it correctly in the *SetCursor* routine, but not in the several *WriteCharacterAndAttribute* calls.

---

> ```
> mov  dl, 0 ; Cursor position column
> mov  dh, 0 ; Cursor position row
> ```

To save space we usually write this pair of instruction as:

```
xor  dx, dx  ;Set CursorColumn=0 CursorRow=0
```

---

> ```
> ; Draw a really simple UI
> ; Draws a blue background
> mov  ah, 09h 
> mov  al, 32
> mov  bl, 10h
> mov  cx, 1000h
> int  10h
> ```

Here you need to verify your understanding of the count in `CX`. It specifies the number of characters that you want to draw. The hexadecimal value 1000h equals **4096** in decimal, but the usual 80x25 textscreen only has **2000** characters to play with! In your program it seems to work OK only because the video memory is much larger than that single display page you're looking at. Nonetheless you should correct it to avoid developing the bad habit of buffer 
overflows.

```
; Draw a really simple UI
; Draws a blue background
mov  ax, 0920h   ;AH=09h Function,     AL=" " Character
mov  bx, 001Fh   ;BH=00h Display page, BL=10h BrightWhiteOnBlue
mov  cx, 2000    ;Character count
int  10h
```

As you can see I combined a pair of settings in a single instruction. This saves space, can be a bit faster, and the comments make it absolutely clear what is going on.

The same applies to drawing the gray bar, although it's not clear:

- why you wrote `160d` with the **d** suffix to specify decimal, as decimal is the default in the absence of any prefix/suffix.
- what you expect to obtain with a counter of 160. It should give you a 2-rows gray bar where you might have expected a 1-row gray bar.

---

When it comes to the compairing section of the program you could definitely tidy up a bit. It will enhance readability a lot.

- Write the comments as tail-comments and keep them aligned
- Write short(er) comments that convey all that is needed
- Replace the ASCII codes by their actual characters
- Don't use double interlineation. (This one is debatable!)

So:

```
cmp  al, 's'    ; The 's' key moves the cursor down
je   Down
cmp  al, 'w'    ; The 'w' key moves the cursor up
je   Up
cmp  al, 'a'    ; The 'a' key moves the cursor left
je   Left
cmp  al, 'd'    ; The 'd' key moves the cursor right
je   Right
cmp  al, ' '    ; The ' ' key makes the background of the cursor magenta
je   SpaceBar
jmp  main       ; Jump back to main
```

---

> ```
>   je   SpaceBar
>   jmp  main
> SpaceBar:
> ```

In a construct like this most programmers will try to save some bytes by using the opposite conditional jump and else fall through:

```
  jne  main
SpaceBar:
```

In this simple program it is what I would do. If the polling section were much longer I would keep what you wrote.

---

> ```
> Right:
>   add  dl, 1
>   call SetCursor
>   jmp  main
>   ret
> ```

The `ret` instruction below a `jmp` is totally useless. The CPU will never reach it. Now it just consumes a byte and is testament of (lack of) skills.

---

In its present form your program entirely depends on the values in `DL` and `DH` having a permanent meaning. If your program were to become longer and more complex, this would no longer be a desirable approach. Then variables would be in order. An example on how to use these:

```
CursorCol  db 0
CursorRow  db 0
  ...
  add  CursorCol, 1
  ...
SetCursor:
  mov  dl, CursorCol
  mov  dh, CursorRow
  mov  bh, 0
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  10h
  ret
```

---

As a final note on the indentations that you used. I've nothing against it **as long as it is used in a consistent manner**. This seems not to be the case! Sometimes the editor on StackExchange/CodeReview is to blame though.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually you're going to want to handle other key-presses, correct? You might also want to handle other encoding styles, like [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), correct?

So, I've never done Assembly before, but these are pretty simple things to design for, and I hope the implementation is correct. First, we want to build a (very large) jump table for [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Essentially, a jump table eliminates all of your comparisons down to exactly one comparison. It's pretty easy to set up:

```
        goto ascii(al) ; Jump to the line of the character code
ascii:  goto nulInput  ; This would be `0` code input
        goto sohInput  ; This would be `1` code input / Start of Heading
        goto stxInput  ; This would be `2` code input / Start of Text
        ; Add End of Text (3), End of Transmission (4), Enquiry (5)
        ; Acknowledgement (6), Bell (7)
        goto bsInput   ; This would be `8` code input / Backspace
        goto htInput   ; This would be `9` code input / Horizontal Tab
        goto lfInput   ; This would be `A` code input / Line Feed
        ; Add Vertical Tab (B), Form Feed (C)
        goto crInput   ; This would be `D` code input / Carriage return
        ; Shift Out (E), Shift In (F), Data Link Escape (10)
        ; Device Control 1 / XON (11), Device Control 2 (12)
        ; Device Control 3 / XOFF (13), Device Control 4 (14)
        ; Negative Acknowledgement (15), Synchronous Idle (16)
        ; End of Transmission Block (17), Cancel (18), End of Medium (19)
        ; Substitute (1A)
        goto escInput   ; This would be `1B` code input / Escape
        ; File Separator (1C), Group Separator (1D), Record Separator (1E)
        ; Unit Separator (1F)
        goto spacInput  ; This would be `20` code input / Space
        goto exclInput  ; This would be `21` code input / Exclamation Point
        ; In Order:
        ; " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ?
        ; @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _
        ; ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~
        goto delInput   ; This would be `7F` code input / Delete
```

So you should get the point, go through the ASCII spec line-by-line and put a line for each record in the spec, then a label for each of those lines. For the ones you don't wish to implement yet, simply have a `restart` label or `badCode` label that ignores the input.

Once that's done we now know how to implement EBCDIC, just build an EBCDIC jump table.

What you might not realize is that having 128 (because eventually you want to support all codes/keys, right?) `cmp` statements will cause negative performance because `al` is compared *up to 128 times* for each key press, that's a lot. So we build a jump table that might be more work to implement initially, but in the end we'll end up with a much easier to maintain setup, and performance will not degrade. When we call `jmp ascii(al)`, it jumps to the `ascii` label, then to the line identified by `al`. Easy stuff.

---

Regarding your indentation and such, from what I've seen usually assembly is spaced fairly far from the left (8-12 spaces) then all labels go at position 0. This helps keep them in plain sight, since assembly doesn't have 'functions' and such, and there's not a real concept of 'nesting' (you can nest labels, but any label can be accessed from any other location/scope so it doesn't always do any good).